# Limit of $\frac{2^{n^k}}{2^{2^n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$\newcommand\iddots{\mathinner{
  \kern1mu\raise1pt{.}
  \kern2mu\raise4pt{.}
  \kern2mu\raise7pt{\Rule{0pt}{7pt}{0pt}.}
  \kern1mu
}}$What is the limit as $n$ tends to infinity of

$$\frac{2^{n^k}}{2^{2^{{\iddots}^2}}},$$

where the denominator is a tower of $n$ twos.

Seems like it should be zero, and I know that $\frac{n^k}{2^n}$ tends to zero.

Comment: To be clear, you mean that the denominator is tetration $2\uparrow\uparrow n$ and not $2^{2^{n-1}}$?

Comment: Yep, correct: tower of 2s

Answer (score 1):

Since $n^k<<2^n$ then $\frac{2^{n^k}}{2^{2^n}}$ tends to $2^{-\infty}=0$.